# How to get the return type of a function in class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, decltype

For example

```
class A
{
    int foo() {return 1;}
    void goo( decltype(((A*)nullptr)->foo()) i) {}
};
```

The `decltype(((A*)nullptr)->foo())` doesn't work here because A is incomplete class. How to do it?

On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/830fdd982167a4e8

Comment: @Deduplicator It [is possible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ca5109e2975c29), but ugly

Comment: There is an underlying problem trying to do this: within the parameter-declaration-clause of `goo`, it is not known if `goo` is `const`, has a ref-qualifier etc. If there are two `foo`, e.g. `int foo(); double foo() const;`, you cannot at this point select an overload. A similar problem occurs when using `decltype` for the return type of a function; this can be solved by using a trailing-return-type.

Comment: @dyp Great. std::typetrait should include it.

Comment: Yes, a type function to decompose member (function) pointer would be quite useful. To write it correctly, you'll need a lot of boilerplate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25045198 (this still lacks `volatile`)

Comment: @dyp: Nice you showed a way to do it. But your explanation for why the direct way fails looks bogus: The decltype used for the argument of `goo` does not in any way depend on the prototype of `goo`.

Comment: @Deduplicator For the OP's code, yes. But one could conceive trying `decltype(foo())` first, or the "equivalent" `decltype(this->foo())`. This won't work for the reason given. Any abstraction from direct name lookup is probably forbidden due to the incompleteness of the type.