# Static member function can access incomplete type's member

Tags: c++, c++11

I found the following code to fail in [gcc](http://rextester.com/AVKG63255) but compile in [clang](http://rextester.com/NKQBX62096).

```c++
struct S
{
    int foo();
    static auto bar() -> decltype(std::declval<S>().foo());
    void baz(decltype(bar()));
};
```

Based on a similar example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446619/how-to-get-the-return-type-of-a-function-in-class) I would expect the code to fail because `S` is an incomplete type within its scope, but I am not sure if there is a special rule for static functions.

Comment: [expr.ref] forbids class member accesses into incomplete classes. *"but I am not sure if there is a special rule for static functions"* It's hard to prove that such a rule does not exist.